# Is there a way to come out on the other side when using a GridLayoutGroup?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface

Let's say I have a GridLayoutGroup that has 4x4 elements. If I'm in the top left and press left is there a way to make it select the bottom right corner element? And if I press up the bottom left and so on?
This is a feature I have seen in a lot of game menus and I wonder whether it's possible to recreate it with the tools already available in Unity.
If not, is there a rather straightforward way to code it yourself?
I don't have much experience with Unity UI yet, so I don't have any idea that fits with the regular ways.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I think what you are looking for is [`Selectable.navigation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-navigation.html) where you can define which object shall be selected next in each direction. So while filling the grid with objects you only would need to tell the last object that when pressing right it should select the first one and the first object that it should select the last one on going left

Comment: Wow, this works like a charm!
Thanks!
If this was an answer instead of a comment, I would mark it as the correct one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [`Selectable.navigation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-navigation.html) where you can define which object shall be selected next in each direction.

So while filling the grid with objects you only would need to tell the last object that when pressing right it should select the first one and the first object that it should select the last one on going left.

E.g. somewhat like

```c#
GridLayoutGroup gridLayoutGroup;

for (var i = 0; i < gridLayoutGroup.transform.childCount; i++)
{
    var selectable = gridLayoutGroup.transform.GetChild(i).GetComponent<Selectable>();
    var navigation = selectable.navigation;

    navigation.mode = Navigation.Mode.Explicit;

    if (i == 0) // first item
    {
        // left -> to next item
        var leftItem = gridLayoutGroup.transform.GetChild(i + 1).GetComponent<Selectable>();
        navigation.selectOnLeft = leftItem;

        // right -> to the last item
        var rightItem = gridLayoutGroup.transform.GetChild(gridLayoutGroup.transform.childCount - 1).GetComponent<Selectable>();
        navigation.selectOnRight = rightItem;
    }
    else if (i == gridLayoutGroup.transform.childCount - 1) // last item
    {
        // left -> to the fist item
        var leftItem = gridLayoutGroup.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Selectable>();
        navigation.selectOnLeft = leftItem;

        // right -> to previous item
        var rightItem = gridLayoutGroup.transform.GetChild(i - 1).GetComponent<Selectable>();
        navigation.selectOnRight = rightItem;
    }
    else // any other item
    {
        // left -> to next item
        var leftItem = gridLayoutGroup.transform.GetChild(i + 1).GetComponent<Selectable>();
        navigation.selectOnLeft = leftItem;

        // right -> to previous item
        var rightItem = gridLayoutGroup.transform.GetChild(i - 1).GetComponent<Selectable>();
        navigation.selectOnRight = rightItem;
    }
}
```